# Get the billing threshold of facebook addaccount using graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can`t find a solution to get billing threshold of facebook addaccount using graph api.

I read all the documentation about facebook marketing and bussiness api, and didn`t find a solution. But i saw that services like fbtool can provide this info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fields adspaymentcycle.to get billing threshold,
ex : act_